# Unable to launch uiautomatorviewer tool

Tags: selenium, appium

I am getting the below error while attempting to launch the UI Automator Viewer tool via command prompt.

> C:\Users\getta\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin>uiautomatorviewer
>   -Djava.ext.dirs=..\lib\x86_64;..\lib is not supported.  Use -classpath instead. Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. Error: A
>   fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

I was googling and it suggested to downgrade Java to v8...any other workarounds apart from that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your all android path properly.

Add a variable in **system environment** as mention below.

**ANDROID_HOME** : C:\Users[Your login name]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (Or any PATH that your android SDK located)

**JAVA_HOME**: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172

**ANDROID_SWT** : C:\Users[Your login name]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\lib\x86_64

**ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS** : C:\Users[Your login name]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools

Add below mention Path in **Path Variable** in the system environment.(If your SDK located in: C:\Users[Your login name]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ )

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk\bin;

C:\Users[Your login name]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin;

C:\Users[Your login name]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools;

C:\Users[Your login name]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools;

C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin;

C:\Users[Your login name]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk;

C:\Users[Your login name]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\lib\x86_64\swt.jar;

**You don't need to downgrade Java version, just have jdk1.8 and then set your JAVA_Home to there**

I have version 10 in my system but also have the other jdks. As you can see in the attached docs, I have version 8 & 10 and the system knows version 10. But I set the JAVA_HOME to jdk 1.8 and it's working well.

[JDK versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEQSH.png)

[What shows by command "java -version"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXhwi.png)

Comment: Thanks for your response.
Please confirm if I need to download 'jdk-8u221-windows-x64.exe' from the below link and install in my machine?
https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/jdk8-downloads.html

Comment: I found that no matter between versions, currently I change the JAVA_HOME to jdk 10.0 and it's working well. I use "Appium 1.12.1" /  JDK 10.0.1 / IntelliJ 2017 / Node 10.15.3 | Windows 10 | 64bit

Comment: Okay, I added the missing system env variables and the path variables as you mentioned, started appium server, launched the avd emulator and then tried opening the uiautomatorviewer tool...same error message!
I use Appium v1.14.2 / JDK 12.0.2 / Eclipse 2019-06(4.12.0) / Node v10.16.3 / Win 10 64-bit

Comment: Installing jdk-8u221-windows-x64 and thereafter setting JAVA_HOME to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221 worked :)
Many thanks mate.

Comment: @Troy tnx for your feedback. If the answer is correct please check the right answer sign for closing the issue.